# Publish multiple private packages to private npm registry (Sinopia)

Tags: sinopia

I have created private npm registry by installing sinopia in the machine, how can i publish multiple private packages by a single publish command instead of publishing one by one ?

I stuck in this step. Please suggest me if you have any idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `npm publish` works in the context of one single module. Why would you do that? Perhaps you are looking for something like this https://github.com/lerna/lerna ?

Comment: Yes Juan, I have bunch of packages that i want to publish on sinopia at one shot. I think lerna is also cool.. thank you..